# Is it ok to use ternary operator in C++ streams?

Tags: c++11, ternary-operator, cout

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A{int number=10;};

int main()
{
   A* a = new A();
   cout<<"A val: "<< a==nullptr?"":a->number<<endl;
}
```

compiling on gcc 4.7 with c++11  gives:

> error: invalid operands of types 'int' and '' to binary 'operator <<'

I do not understand why, what would be to proper way to do it? I want to keep null checks as short as possible as I expect them to be very common.

Comment: The ternary operator has [a surprising low precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) for most people. My suggestion: avoid it, whenever you are not absolutely sure what it does: your colleagues will thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: yes, you can use the ternary operator for an `std::ostream`, but **beware of operator precedence**.  If you are going to do so, you need to do something like this:

```
cout << "My name is: " << (my != nullptr ? my->name() : "don't know") << '\n';
```

In other words, encapsulate the ternary expression in parentheses.

Second, the second and third operands must be convertible to the same type.  In other words, your example won't work because you are trying to insert a string literal (`""`) if `a` is null, or the actual number (`a->number`, which is of type `int`) if `a` is not null.

Third, you need to fix the syntax.  But @quamrana already addressed that one.

Answer (score 1):

You are finding that operator `<<` binds differently than you expect.

Use:

```
cout << "A val: " << (a==nullptr ? "" : a->number) << endl;
```

(or have you just made a typo and missed the `:` from `?:`)

Comment: I find it a bit misleading to focus *first* on the left shift operator while the question is about the ternary operator. But eventually you are right: the "comfort" of `<<` and  '>>' is limited to every-day maths when calculating expressions for I/O on the fly. And that's why it's more efficient to learn using parentheses for stream I/O then just staring at the extremely low precedence of the ternary operator...